# MS Access excel formula to Access

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007

How do I make this formula work in MS Access 07. I have tried to build it with expression builder but it just gives me the Name error.

```
=IF(SEX="M",IF(AGE<30,PUSHUPS-20,IF(AGE<40, PUSHUPS -17,IF(AGE<50, PUSHUPS -13,
 IF(AGE<100, PUSHUPS-4,0)))),IF(AGE<30, PUSHUPS -1,IF(AGE<40, 
 PUSHUPS,IF(AGE<50, PUSHUPS +3,IF(AGE<100, PUSHUPS +9,0)))))
```

Any help would be great, thank you guys. Happy Holiday.

Comment: You want to use the IIF function in Access

Comment: AS Tim Lentine said: just replace IF with IIF and it work. =IIf([SEX]="M",IIf([AGE]<30,[PUSHUPS]-20,IIf([AGE]<40,[PUSHUPS]-17,IIf([AGE]<50,[PUSHUPS]-13,IIf([AGE]<100,[PUSHUPS]-4,0)))),IIf([AGE]<30,[PUSHUPS]-1,IIf([AGE]<40,[PUSHUPS],IIf([AGE]<50,[PUSHUPS]+3,IIf([AGE]<100,[PUSHUPS]+9,0)))))

Comment: I'll try that again but it just kept giving me the  Name error.

Comment: I'm receiving a message now that says "The expression you entered contains invalid syntax.  You may have entered an operand without an operator."                                                                             Does anyone know what this means, I'm very novice with Access and just learning it but I can get that expression to work.

Answer (score 1):

Two options, use `IIF` or use `SWITCH`

```
=IIF(SEX="M",IIF(AGE<30,PUSHUPS-20,IIF(AGE<40, PUSHUPS -17,IIF(AGE<50, PUSHUPS -13, IIF(AGE<100, PUSHUPS-4,0)))),IIF(AGE<30, PUSHUPS -1,IIF(AGE<40,  PUSHUPS,IIF(AGE<50,  PUSHUPS +3,IIF(AGE<100, PUSHUPS +9,0)))))


=iif(SEX="M",Switch(AGE<30, PUSHUPS-20, AGE<40, PUSHUPS -17, AGE<50, PUSHUPS -13, AGE<100, PUSHUPS-4),switch(AGE<30, PUSHUPS -1, AGE<40,  PUSHUPS, AGE<50,  PUSHUPS +3, AGE<100, PUSHUPS +9))
```

I think Switch is easier to read.